# write a query in esper for time frame checking values for each event..

Tags: esper

I am trying to write a query for events , and the even has a Boolean value . 
I want to write a query that checks the value of that Boolean status in last five seconds ..
passing criteria:- the value of Boolean must be false at all the occurrence within last 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of 
 `select * from Event.win:time(5) having count(*, value=false) = count(*) and count(*) > 0` 
 The EPL allows you to add some expression to the "count(*)" counting only those events that satisfy the expression.